# ArangoDB Replication ServerID duplicate between different servers

Tags: arangodb

I installed arangodb2.0.6 (with the APP) in two OSX 10.9 different machines, inside our own internal network (not connected directly to internet)

I correctly configured replication logger in machine A for database 'MyDB'.

I configured replication applier in database 'MyDB' in machine B pointing to A with no start tick and started it, returning "running":"true".

But the applier stops immediately with error: 
lastError": {
      "errorMessage": "got same server id (190048212006786) from endpoint 'tcp://x.x.x.x:8002' as the local applier server's id",
    },

If via the HTTP API I call /_api/replication/server-id in machine A and B, I got the same serverId: 190048212006786.

What is the way you assign the serverId? Is based on arangodb version / OS version / external IP.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ArangoDB under MacOSX and will be fixed in 2.1.1. It always generates the same server id. Under Linux and Windows different id are generated based on some random values.

To fix the situation under MacOSX. Shut down one server and edit the file SERVER in the database directory (change the id to some other value).

The file should look like

```
{"serverId":"190048212006786","createdTime":"2014-06-06T08:20:20Z"}
```

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot! Congratulations for the software!

Comment: I'm on Windows and I've upgraded several times and always had this issue. I've always had to edit the SERVER file so that my dev database has a different ID than the production DB. Any ideas?

Comment: @fceller I have the same issue on AWS EC2 Ubuntu. Where I find this file?